# Dimensional analysis of quantized Klein-Gordon Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, dimensional-analysis, klein-gordon-equation

For the free Klein-Gordon Lagrangian density:
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial^{\mu}\phi\partial_{\mu} \phi-m^2\phi^2 .$$
Since we need the dimension of Lagrangian density equal to 4 (in this case action dimension $[S]=0$ in 4D spacetime).

And the kinetic term usually have a large contribution, we infer from $\partial^{\mu}\phi\partial_{\mu}\phi$ that the dimension of $\phi$ is 1.

If we quantize $\phi$, (as in Peskin and Schroder's book)
$$ \phi(x)=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 E_{\mathbf{p}}}}\left(a_{\mathbf{p}} e^{-i p \cdot x}+a_{\mathbf{p}}^{\dagger} e^{i p \cdot x}\right).\tag{2.25/2.47}$$
I know that the creation and annihilation operator need to have dimension 1, since they related with one-particle state. This means that the dimension of
$$\left[\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 E_{\mathbf{p}}}}\right]=0 $$
From non-trivial thinking $E_{\mathbf{p}}$ should have dimension 1, so where is my problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "Since we need the dimension of Lagrangian equal to 4"? Lagrangian is a scalar function

Comment: @basics as in the dimension of the Lagrangian is $m^4$.

Comment: _I know that the creation and annihilation operator need to have dimension 1._ Not so fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know that the creation and annihilation operator need to have dimension 1, since they related with one-particle state.

I don't know what rule you think you're using, but this is wrong. Each ladder operator has dimension $-\frac32$ because$$[a_\mathbf{p},\,a^\dagger_\mathbf{q}]=(2\pi)^3\delta^3(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{q})$$is of dimension $-3$.